# Will search engine web crawlers see urls that are changed with HTML5 history?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, html5

I have a site where the different language versions are on the same url. If the language is not set as a get variable, language is set by a session variable in php, and the url is rewritten correspondingly with [html5 history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) pushState. Will search engine web crawlers see these new urls?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it. It even looks like Google [recommends using pushShate](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) and [prefers it over hash bangs](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-ajax-pushstate-vs-hashbang-16464.html).